# How to detect clashes in multiple istio authorization policies?

Tags: istio

Given the case that the same path, e.g. `/test`, is configured differently in two different Istio AuthorizationPolicy, how can this conflict be detected and prevented?

I had such a case and it is not clear how Istio decides which config takes precedence and if the behavior is deterministic.